# Word 2016 Add-in blocked from accessing data for some Windows users

Tags: ms-office, office365, office-js

I've got a mysterious edge case with some Word 2016 users on Windows using my Word add-in.

I realize much more info might be required...but I also feel this is an issue that might have some proven ways to diagnose - or someone may know of a root cause.

My simple Word add-in pulls data from a MySQL db on my web server (via php) and stores it in localstorage. Works great in Word 2016 on multiple computers. A handful of users can't, essentially, download data and my solution throws errors for them.

I've even had 2 users on the same machine - one who can use my add-in, one who cannot (so each logging into different Windows accounts at the same institution. The user who was able to happily use my app is in IT and maybe had different settings).

My nose tells me there is an Internet Explorer security setting getting in the way...we've verified that localstorage is allowed.

When a user with the problem opens Internet Explorer directly, they're able to download data and use the app (part of it works outside of Word). As I understand it, Word 2016 Add-ins use Internet Explorer 11 to render html/js/css - and a setting changed in a user's IE11 settings area will cascade to Word 2016 add-ins.

Some of the weird details I've picked up:

- Opening a new browser window from inside Word (clicking on a link in my add-in that opens a full web browser) prompts a "A website wants to open web content using this program on your computer" and points to Internet Explorer's **Protected Mode**. I've experimented with turning this on myself and can't recreate the issue.
- The user isn't signed into O365. That doesn't seem to make a difference either.

Debugging via F12Chooser shows an [object error] with an error code of "-2147024891" and a "stack" message of "Error: Access is denied..." at the point where data would be pulled...I can't get much more out of the console.

The add-in is able to hit Firebase (I'm using Google's Firebase for authentication) and I get a response from their server...but not my ajax call to my php file.

Any thought or direction appreciated.